# Question on definition of augmented filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In Protter's book *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, it defines usual hypotheses as follows:

> A filtered complete probability space
> $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F_t}\},P)$ is said to satisfy the
> usual hypotheses if
>
> (i) $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all the P-null sets of $\mathcal{F}$;
>
> (ii) $\{\mathcal{F_t}\}$ is right-continuous.

I want to know what is 'P-null sets of $\mathcal{F}$'. Do we need that a P-null sets of $\mathcal{F}$ must be in $\mathcal{F}$?

In Le Gall's book *GTM274*, it defines as follows:

> Let $\{\mathcal{F_t}\}$ be a filtration and let $\mathcal{N}$ be the
> class of all  $(\mathcal{F_\infty},P)$ negligible sets (i.e.
> $A\in\mathcal{N}$ if there exists an $A^{\prime}\in\mathcal{F_\infty}$
> such $A\subset A^{\prime}$ and $P(A^{\prime})=0.$)
>
> The filtration is said to be complete if
> $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{F_0}$ (and thus
> $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{F_t}$ for every t).

In this definition, we don't need set in $\mathcal{N}$ to be in $\mathcal{F}$. So I am really confusiong now.

Comment: Well unless mistaken there is morally no difference between Protter's and Le Gall's book on this as in almost all contexts $\mathcal{F_\infty}=\mathcal{F}$, if $\mathcal{F}$ contains more null sets though it won't hurt any result at all. The usual hypotheses are here so that right continuous versions of local martingales always exists if I remember well, you can check this on George Lowther's blog (google Almost Sure blog). Regards